# How do i acess/map the name field of cities array inside the cities array in following json in dart/flutter

Tags: json, flutter, dart

```
    {
      "cities": [
        {
          
          "cities": [
            {
              "name": "Adilabad",      
            },
            {
              "name": "Afjalpur",
            },
           ]
},]
}
```

I am using Bloc pattern and trying to load the data in sugestions of SearchField.

I can access cities array like this -> state.cities.map((e) => e.city).toList();

but how can i access the name inside the array

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following to get the city name.

```
  Map map = {
    "cities": [
      {
        "cities": [
          {
            "name": "Adilabad",
          },
          {
            "name": "Afjalpur",
          },
        ]
      },
    ]
  }; //´´
  final cities = map['cities'][0]['cities'];
  print(map['cities'][0]['cities']); // [{name: Adilabad}, {name: Afjalpur}]
  print(cities[0]['name']); // Adilabad
```